# Is it possible to verify a python code produced an answer without re-doing the computation?

Tags: hash, signature, verifiability, computational-complexity-theory

### Context

Suppose Alice asks Bob to write a (python) code/function named `get_sqrt(input)` that computes and returns the square root of an input number named `input`. Next, Alice provides three random numbers as `input` to Bob. Bob produces the three `output` numbers using Bob's function `get_sqrt(input)` and returns to Alice:

- Three `output` numbers that are the square roots of the three `input` numbers.
- The python code `get_sqrt(input)`.
- Some kind of signature/hash code. This signature/hash code can consist of any combination of information derived from the `input`, `output` and python code `get_sqrt(input)`.

### Assumptions

1. Alice only has access to Alice's world until Alice has verified the solution of Bob. Afterwards Alice gets access to both Alice's and Bob's world.
2. Bob has access to both Bob's world and Alice's world (low- and high costs per operations).
3. Bob can do computations cheaply in Bob's world, but Bob is not trusted in Bob's world.
4. Re-doing the computation is too expensive in the world of Alice (for both Bob and Alice), because in the world of Alice, the costs per computation are too high.
5. The solutions created by the function `get_sqrt(input)` are reversible or easily(polynomially) verifiable. (For example, the output of Bob's function `get_sqrt(input)` can be verified by Alice by checking whether the square of each `output` equals its accompanying `input`.)

### Challenge

However, just that the answers provided by Bob are correct, does not mean that the `get_sqrt(input)` function that Bob sent to Alice actually generated those answers/isn't gibberish. Therefore, I was wondering if there is some property that can be computed by Bob (and/or Alice), based on the `input`, `output`, and (python) code `get_sqrt(input)` that makes it possible for Alice to verify that Bob's function indeed generates those `output` numbers based on the given `input` numbers (without re-doing the computations).

### Question

Is there a way with which Alice can verify that the `output` numbers are generated by the `get_sqrt(input)` function based on the set of `input` numbers, without re-doing the computation?

Comment: Is it sufficient for you to validate that Bob is able to perform such computations or do you _need_ to validate that a specific piece of code was executed?

Comment: There is no *need* to validate that a specific piece of code was executed. It is *not* sufficient to validate that Bob is able to perform such computations. It is sufficient to validate that Alice is able to reproduce the computations (later-on (in a different environment where the costs per operation are lower).

Comment: Do you trust Bob, it seems no. Then why doesn't Alice verifies in the first place? I think this is not your actual question.

Comment: Bob is not trusted, but able to do all computations in a cheap environment. Alice can't verify the code by re-computing it because the cost per operation are too high in the world of Alice. Bob has access to both the cheap- and expensive cost per operation worlds. But the costs per operations of verifying in Alice's world (by means of re-computation) are also too high for Bob.